# Importing a class in main() function in python

Tags: python

I am trying to import a module in my `main()` method (entry point in sender module) and pass user input arguments to it. The module will create a json data structure. However, I cannot import this module. My IDE cannot resolve it. 
Here is the main function:

```
def main():
    from directioncontroller import controller

    args = create_parser().parse_args()
    json_message(args.direction)
    print("Sending direction %s" % args.direction )
```

And the controller module:

```
import json

def json_message(direction):
    data = {}
    data['instruction'] = 'direction'
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    return json_data
```

I have specified my entry point in my setup file in the following way:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open('README.rst', 'r') as f:
    readme = f.read()

setup(
    name='practice',
    version='0.1.0',
    description='Direction Controller',
    long_description=readme,
    author='user',
    author_email='user@email.com',
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    package_dir={'':'src'},
    install_requires=[],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'directioncontroller=directioncontroller.sender:main'
        ]
    }

)
```

Why is the class not identified in my package?

Comment: I don't know for sure but my guess would be because it's defined *in* the function and not at the top of the file as is customary. Is there a particular reason you're not doing that?

Comment: Your IDE is probably not configured correctly. Which IDE are you using? What happens when you try to run the code?

Comment: I used pipenv shell and ` pip install -e` Once I run the `directioncontroller --direction start` I get data {
  "instruction": "start",
}
"Sending direction...". So I think the issue is just with IDE.